# How to add the aliases to the group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

In the below query how to add the aliases `assignedTOiti`, `assignedTOasstAdm`, `assignedTOhlp`, `closedDate` to the group by clause.

I am struggling for the past few hours.

```
SELECT ieor.aper07_req_k                                  AS reqno,
       ford.apeh09_supervisor_cds_d                       AS ll6CdsID,
       'Ford Offboard Req'                                AS reqtype,
       par_val1.aper17_parameter_val_x                    AS requeststatus,
       (SELECT Min(iti2.aper07_req_created_s)
        FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req iti2
        WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = iti2.aper07_req_k
               AND iti2.aper06_req_status_k = 4)          AS assignedTOiti,
       (SELECT Min(hlp2.aper07_req_created_s)
        FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req hlp2
        WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = hlp2.aper07_req_k
               AND hlp2.aper06_req_status_k = 5)          AS assignedTOasstAdm,
       (SELECT Min(asst2.aper07_req_created_s)
        FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req asst2
        WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = asst2.aper07_req_k
               AND asst2.aper06_req_status_k = 12)        AS assignedTOhlp,
       (SELECT Min(clsd2.aper07_req_created_s)
        FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req clsd2
        WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = clsd2.aper07_req_k
               AND clsd2.aper06_req_status_k IN ( 3, 9 )) AS closedDate,
       ieor.aper07_assigned_to_cds_d,
       ieor.aper07_comment_x,
       ieor.aper07_last_updt_user_c,
       ieor.aper07_last_updt_s                            AS last,
       ieor.apeh09_employee_k,
       ieor.aper06_req_status_k,
       ipw.apeh04_first_n,
       ipw.apeh04_cds_d,
       ipw.apeh04_last_n,
       ipw.apeh04_person_type_c,
       irs.aper06_req_status_x,
       offr.aper15_offboard_reason_x                      AS offboardReason,
       Min(aper07_req_created_s)                          AS creationDate
FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req ieor,
       iapeh05_person_vw ipw,
       iapeh09_ford_employee ford,
       iaper06_req_status irs,
       iaper15_offbrd_req_reason offr,
       iaper17_parameter_values par_val1
WHERE  ford.apeh09_cds_d = ipw.apeh04_cds_d
       AND ieor.apeh09_employee_k = ipw.apeh04_visitor_k
       AND irs.aper06_req_status_k = ieor.aper06_req_status_k
       AND offr.aper15_offboard_reason_k = ieor.aper15_offboard_reason_k
       AND ieor.aper06_req_status_k = par_val1.aper17_parameter_val_r
       AND ipw.apeh22_region_k = 1
       AND ieor.aper07_last_updt_s = (SELECT Max(aper07_last_updt_s)
                                      FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b
                                      WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = b.aper07_req_k)
       AND ieor.aper07_req_k = 3387
GROUP  BY ieor.aper07_req_k,
          ford.apeh09_supervisor_cds_d,
          ieor.aper07_assigned_to_cds_d,
          ieor.aper07_comment_x,
          ieor.aper07_last_updt_user_c,
          ieor.aper07_last_updt_s,
          ieor.apeh09_employee_k,
          ieor.aper06_req_status_k,
          ipw.apeh04_first_n,
          ipw.apeh04_cds_d,
          ipw.apeh04_last_n,
          ipw.apeh04_person_type_c,
          irs.aper06_req_status_x,
          par_val1.aper17_parameter_val_x,
          offr.aper15_offboard_reason_x
HAVING ipw.apeh04_person_type_c NOT IN( 'c', 'C' )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. Aliasses can be used only in a select over the current one.

There are two sollutions for your problem:

```
select a+b as newcol
from table
group by a+b;
```

or

```
select newcol
from
   (select a+b as newcol
     from table)
group by newcol;
```

For your query I suggest this:

```
select 
  reqno,
  ll6CdsID,
  reqtype,
  requeststatus,
  assignedTOiti,
  assignedTOasstAdm,
  assignedTOhlp,
  closedDate,
  aper07_assigned_to_cds_d,
  aper07_comment_x,
  aper07_last_updt_user_c,
  last,
  apeh09_employee_k,
  aper06_req_status_k,
  apeh04_first_n,
  apeh04_cds_d,
  apeh04_last_n,
  apeh04_person_type_c,
  aper06_req_status_x,
  offboardReason,
  Min(creationDate) AS creationDate
FROM

    (SELECT ieor.aper07_req_k                              AS reqno,
           ford.apeh09_supervisor_cds_d                   AS ll6CdsID,
           'Ford Offboard Req'                            AS reqtype,
           par_val1.aper17_parameter_val_x                AS requeststatus,
           (SELECT Min(iti2.aper07_req_created_s)
            FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req iti2
            WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = iti2.aper07_req_k
                   AND iti2.aper06_req_status_k = 4)      AS assignedTOiti,
           (SELECT Min(hlp2.aper07_req_created_s)
            FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req hlp2
            WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = hlp2.aper07_req_k
                   AND hlp2.aper06_req_status_k = 5)      AS assignedTOasstAdm,
           (SELECT Min(asst2.aper07_req_created_s)
            FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req asst2
            WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = asst2.aper07_req_k
                   AND asst2.aper06_req_status_k = 12)    AS assignedTOhlp,
           (SELECT Min(clsd2.aper07_req_created_s)
            FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req clsd2
            WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = clsd2.aper07_req_k
                   AND clsd2.aper06_req_status_k IN ( 3, 9 )) AS closedDate,
           ieor.aper07_assigned_to_cds_d,
           ieor.aper07_comment_x,
           ieor.aper07_last_updt_user_c,
           ieor.aper07_last_updt_s                            AS last,
           ieor.apeh09_employee_k,
           ieor.aper06_req_status_k,
           ipw.apeh04_first_n,
           ipw.apeh04_cds_d,
           ipw.apeh04_last_n,
           ipw.apeh04_person_type_c,
           irs.aper06_req_status_x,
           offr.aper15_offboard_reason_x                      AS offboardReason,
           aper07_req_created_s                          AS creationDate
    FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req ieor,
           iapeh05_person_vw ipw,
           iapeh09_ford_employee ford,
           iaper06_req_status irs,
           iaper15_offbrd_req_reason offr,
           iaper17_parameter_values par_val1
    WHERE  ford.apeh09_cds_d = ipw.apeh04_cds_d
           AND ieor.apeh09_employee_k = ipw.apeh04_visitor_k
           AND irs.aper06_req_status_k = ieor.aper06_req_status_k
           AND offr.aper15_offboard_reason_k = ieor.aper15_offboard_reason_k
           AND ieor.aper06_req_status_k = par_val1.aper17_parameter_val_r
           AND ipw.apeh22_region_k = 1
           AND ieor.aper07_last_updt_s = (SELECT Max(aper07_last_updt_s)
                                          FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b
                                          WHERE  ieor.aper07_req_k = b.aper07_req_k)
           AND ieor.aper07_req_k = 3387
    )
WHERE apeh04_person_type_c NOT IN( 'c', 'C' )
GROUP  BY   reqno,
  ll6CdsID,
  reqtype,
  requeststatus,
  assignedTOiti,
  assignedTOasstAdm,
  assignedTOhlp,
  closedDate,
  aper07_assigned_to_cds_d,
  aper07_comment_x,
  aper07_last_updt_user_c,
  last,
  apeh09_employee_k,
  aper06_req_status_k,
  apeh04_first_n,
  apeh04_cds_d,
  apeh04_last_n,
  apeh04_person_type_c,
  aper06_req_status_x,
  offboardReason
```

I moved the having clause to a WHERE clause, though it can be put in the inner select to WHERE clause.

Comment: can you help me with ur second suggestion...with relevance to my query.SInce my select clause consists of a subquery and not a column..which is what am not able to do..

Comment: thank you so much..Florin..but when i implement the query i get a null value in one of the columns say assigned to help where data is actually present.

Comment: Take the inner query, remove what is unrelated to `assigned to help` and see what is wrong. Proabably a wrong condition, or wrong join.

Answer (score 2):

The group by clause groups the data before the SELECT displays the selected column. At this stage, the aliases in select clause aren't defined, and hence you can't use them in GROUP BY.

Ugly workaround is to replace the alias with the actual statements/functions that are being used.